# interaction with grob using grid and gridSVG

Tags: r

I actually have no idea with this does not work!

```
library(grid)
library(gridSVG)
grid.newpage()
vp <- viewport(width=0.7, height=0.7)
pushViewport(vp)

grid.rect(x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      width = unit(0.5, "npc"), height = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      just = "centre", hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL,
      default.units = "npc", name = "grid.rect.1",
      gp=gpar(), draw = TRUE)
```

this works:

```
grid.garnish("grid.rect.1",onmousedown="alert('alert 1!')","pointer-events"="all")
grid.export("gridSVG1.svg")
```

this doesn't work

```
grid.garnish("grid.rect.1", onmouseover="allwhite()", redraw = TRUE)

grid.script("allwhite = function() {
anobject = document.getElementById('grid.rect.1.1');
anobject.setAttribute('style', 'fill:red');
}", name="allwhite")

grid.export("gridSVG2.svg") # saved to your current working directory
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is that the rectangle is filled with red if I'm hovering over the rectangle with my mouse.

Due to the fact, that this is my first encounter with js, I have to ask maybe this silly question. I'm aware of the fact, that I name the spline "grid.rect.1" but use "grid.rect.1.1" in the script part. This is just a matter of despair, due to the fact, that I realize that rect has this id, if I inspect the SVG object with Google Chrome.

I'm using Google Chrome (36.0.1985.125 m) to watch the SVG object and it seems that a somewhat simpler thing works

As always, any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like you can't add attributes, so your `rect` needs a fill `gpar`. You'll also need to fix the id of the `rect` element. If you look at the source, you'll see that "grid.rect.1.1" is actually the grouping tag.

```
library(grid)
library(gridSVG)
grid.newpage()
vp <- viewport(width=0.7, height=0.7)
pushViewport(vp)

grid.rect(x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      width = unit(0.5, "npc"), height = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      just = "centre", hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL,
      default.units = "npc", name = "grid.rect.1",
      gp=gpar(fill='white'),  # add fill parameter
      draw = TRUE)

grid.garnish("grid.rect.1", onmouseover="allwhite()", `pointer-events`='all')

grid.script("allwhite = function() {
anobject = document.getElementById('grid.rect.1.1.1');
anobject.setAttribute('style', 'fill:red');
}", name="allwhite")

grid.export("gridSVG2.svg")
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Unfortunately now I'm able to work on my project on the coming weekend :-)